# GridView_RowUpdating method doesn't works in my asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, web-applications

I have an asp.net project, in which columns in GridView adding manually by button click, here's the method:

```
protected void addVacations_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into vacations(id,name,date,nodes) values(DEFAULT, @imya, @data, @primVac)", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@imya", imya.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@data", data.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@primVac", primVac.Text));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }

    }
```

I have two others buttons, that adding change GridView's columns by clicking them.
  Now i have to add opportunity to change them online by clients. Here's the GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="1650px" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" >
```

Here's GridView1_RowUpdating method:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
 GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            int ID5 = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
            string name = (row.FindControl("name") as TextBox).Text;
            string date = (row.FindControl("date") as TextBox).Text;
            string prim = (row.FindControl("nodes") as TextBox).Text;

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["postgresConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (NpgsqlConnection cn = new NpgsqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string query = "UPDATE vacations SET name=@name,date=@date,nodes=@prim Where id=@ID5";
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, cn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = name;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = date;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@nodes", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = prim;             
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = ID5;
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Right now i have next error when trying to change rows:
**Server error in the application '/'.
The object reference does not point to an instance of the object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Examine the stack trace for more information about this error and the code snippet that caused it.
Exception Information: System.NullReferenceException: The object reference does not point to an instance of the object.
Source error:
Line 361:            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Line 362:            int ID5 = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
Line 363:            string name = (row.FindControl("name") as TextBox).Text;
The problem exactly in Line 363**
I think the problem in my string, if be exact here:

```
string name = (row.FindControl("name") as TextBox).Text;
        string date = (row.FindControl("date") as TextBox).Text;
        string prim = (row.FindControl("nodes") as TextBox).Text;
```

So i need help how to correctly declare my strings? Or what wrong in my code.

Update. Here is my column details, all three buttons:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = null;//надо удалить текущие колонны (columns)
        GridView1.DataBind();
        for (int i = 0; GridView1.Columns.Count > i;)
        {
            GridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();

            bf1.HeaderText = "Направление деятельности";
            bf1.DataField = "lineofbusiness";
            bf1.ReadOnly = true;
            bf1.SortExpression = "Napr";

            bf2.HeaderText = "Объект";
            bf2.DataField = "object";
            bf2.SortExpression = "Obj";

            bf3.HeaderText = "Мероприятия";
            bf3.DataField = "events";
            bf3.SortExpression = "Merop";

            bf4.HeaderText = "Срок";
            bf4.DataField = "deadline";
            bf4.SortExpression = "Srok";

            bf5.HeaderText = "Примечания";
            bf5.DataField = "nodes";
            bf5.SortExpression = "Prim";

            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf1);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf2);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf3);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf4);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf5);

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
            NpgsqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, lineofbusiness, object, events, deadline, nodes FROM mainpage where executor = '" + (string)Session["Name"] + "'  ", conn);
            //NpgsqlDataAdapter sqlDa1 = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT lineofbusiness, object, events, deadline, nodes FROM mainpage where executor = '" + curentExec + "'  ", conn); //показ по исполнителю(раб код)
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();

            sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
            GridView1.DataSource = dtbl;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Panel1.Visible = true;
            Panel3.Visible = false;
            //conn.Close(); //надо ли?                       
        }

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = null;//надо удалить текущие колонны (columns)
        GridView1.DataBind();
        for (int i = 0; GridView1.Columns.Count > i;)
        {
            GridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();

            bf1.HeaderText = "Номер";
            bf1.DataField = "id";
            bf1.ReadOnly = true;
            bf1.SortExpression = "11";

            //bf2.HeaderText = "ФИО";
            //bf2.DataField = "name";
            //bf2.SortExpression = "22";

            bf3.HeaderText = "Место";
            bf3.DataField = "place";
            bf3.SortExpression = "33";

            bf4.HeaderText = "Цель";
            bf4.DataField = "target";
            bf4.SortExpression = "44";

            bf5.HeaderText = "Срок";
            bf5.DataField = "date";
            bf5.SortExpression = "44";

            bf6.HeaderText = "Результат";
            bf6.DataField = "result";
            bf6.SortExpression = "44";

            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf1);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf2);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf3);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf4);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf5);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf6);

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
            //NpgsqlDataAdapter sqlDavac = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM trips", conn);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter sqlDavac = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, place, target, date, result FROM trips where name = '" + (string)Session["Name"] + "'  ", conn);
            DataTable dtblvac = new DataTable();

            sqlDavac.Fill(dtblvac);
            GridView1.DataSource = dtblvac;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            Panel1.Visible = false;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Panel3.Visible = true;
        }

    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = null;//надо удалить текущие колонны (columns)
        GridView1.DataBind();
        for (int i = 0; GridView1.Columns.Count > i;)
        {
            GridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();

            bf1.HeaderText = "Номер";
            bf1.DataField = "id";
            bf1.ReadOnly = true;
            bf1.SortExpression = "NomerVac";               

            //bf2.HeaderText = "ФИО";
            //bf2.DataField = "name";
            //bf2.SortExpression = "NameVac";

            bf3.HeaderText = "Дата";
            bf3.DataField = "date";
            bf3.SortExpression = "DataVac";

            bf4.HeaderText = "Примечания";
            bf4.DataField = "nodes";
            bf4.SortExpression = "PrimVac";

            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf1);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf2);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf3);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf4);

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
           //NpgsqlDataAdapter sqlDavac = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM vacations", conn);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter sqlDavac = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, date, nodes FROM vacations where name = '" + (string)Session["Name"] + "'  ", conn);
            DataTable dtblvac = new DataTable();

            sqlDavac.Fill(dtblvac);
            GridView1.DataSource = dtblvac;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            Panel1.Visible = false;
            Panel2.Visible = true;
            Panel3.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide column details to your `GridView` markup? I think the problem occurred because `FindControl` doesn't found any control with specified name and returns null, then `Text` property access trigger NRE.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto i'm added in Update section

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto Hello my friend! Do you have any ideas?